# Python cannot find protobuf file

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I have some compiled ProtoBuf classes that I'm trying to use the REPL against. However, attempting to import the base message class fails when it tries to pull in one of the sub-classes:

```
phrogz:~$ ll lib/*.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz  8570 Oct  7 15:08 lib/api_pb2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz 30433 Oct  7 15:08 lib/bar_pb2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz 22333 Oct  7 15:08 lib/foo_pb2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz 21681 Oct  7 15:08 lib/jam_pb2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz  6739 Oct  7 15:08 lib/jim_pb2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz     0 Jul 28 11:26 lib/__init__.py

phrogz:~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from lib import api_pb2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phrogz/lib/api_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    import bar_pb2 as bar__pb2
ImportError: No module named 'bar_pb2'
```

What do I need to modify so that everyone knows to look in the `lib` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the `lib` directory prior to entering the REPL, e.g.

```
phrogz:~$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:./lib
phrogz:~$ python3
```